# to_categorical() of tensorflow keras Error :Unable to allocate 221. GiB for an array with shape (3324240, 17877) and data type float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Whenever I run the code below, I receive the following error:

```
Unable to allocate 221. GiB for an array with shape (3324240, 17877) and data type float32.
```

The general logic of the code is as follows: I load a punctuation-free text from a CSV file using pandas. 'Important' words are those that appear in the text frequently enough. The encoder and decoder are used for keras's seq2seq and both are the numpy arrays of the text, which are loaded from the CSV so that the model can be trained on them.

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Input, LSTM
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.utils import pad_sequences
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

word2count = {}
for _, line in df.iterrows():
    for word in line['no_punc'].split():
        if word not in word2count:
            word2count[word] = 1
        else:
            word2count[word] += 1

important_word={}
thresh = 5
important_word['<PAD>'] = 0
word_id = 1
for key, value in word2count.items():
    if value > thresh:
        important_word[key] = word_id
        word_id += 1

questions = {}
answers = {}

for q, ans in convo_line.items():
    questions[q] = df.loc[q, 'no_punc']
    answers[ans] = df.loc[ans, 'no_punc']

for key, value in answers.items():
    answers[key] = '<SOS>' + value + '<EOS>'

tokens=['<EOS>', '<OUT>', '<SOS>']

x = len(important_word)

for t in tokens:
    important_word[t] = x
    x += 1

encoder_inp = []
for id, line in questions.items():
    lst = []
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in important_word:
            lst.append(important_word['<OUT>'])
        else:
            lst.append(important_word[word])
    encoder_inp.append(lst)

decoder_inp = []

for id, line in answers.items():
    lst=[]
    for word in line.split():
        if word not in important_word:
            lst.append(important_word['<OUT>'])
        else:
            lst.append(important_word[word])
    decoder_inp.append(lst)

encoder_inp = pad_sequences(encoder_inp, 15, padding='post', truncating='post')
decoder_inp = pad_sequences(decoder_inp, 15, padding='post', truncating='post')

decoder_inp_final = []

for i in decoder_inp:
    decoder_inp_final.append(i[1:])

decoder_inp_final = pad_sequences(decoder_inp_final, 15, padding='post', truncating='post')

de = decoder_inp_final[:17876]
decoder_inp_final = to_categorical(decoder_inp_final)
```

Error message:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[183], line 2
      1 de=decoder_inp_final[:17876]
----> 2 decoder_inp_final=to_categorical(decoder_inp_final)

File d:\Desktop AI\env\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\np_utils.py:73, in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
     71     num_classes = np.max(y) + 1
     72 n = y.shape[0]
---> 73 categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
     74 categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
     75 output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 221. GiB for an array with shape (3324240, 17877) and data type float32
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a gigantic amount of data. Your decoder_inp_final is a matrix of size 3M x 18K, thus it has roughly 60Bilion floats. It is just too much for your machine memory.

It is highly unlikely you actually need to load 3M tokens into memory at once, you should rewrite your code to do so in randomized chunks, do the update, load the new chunk etc.

Comment: how do you randomize the data chunks ?